# protoc jar maven plugin intellij not creating compiled proto files

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am trying to use the [protoc jar maven plugin](https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar-maven-plugin) in intelij. I've added this to my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
            <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeDirectories>
                            <include>src/main/protobuf</include>
                        </includeDirectories>
                        <inputDirectories>
                            <include>src/main/protobuf</include>
                        </inputDirectories>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have a proto file located at `src/main/protobuf`. I also have this in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
        <artifactId>protoc-jar</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is the proto:

```
package stringtest;

message StringObject {
    repeated string string_one = 1;
    repeated string string_two = 2;
    repeated string string_three = 3;
}
```

However, whenever I right click on my module and click build, or if I go to the Build menu and hit Build project, I do not see any compiled protobuf files being generated. I also do not see any errors. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I am trying to figure out the same...

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't. I think I'm just going to write a script to use protoc and generate the classes for me. It's annoying, but at least it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .proto file is in your resources folder
src/main/resources and your pom.xml can be anywhere within the src folder when you run maven install. You should see your files within your main java folder be generated.

Answer (score 0):

We have used this below plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${protobuf.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.4.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                </protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>
                    io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                </pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        <goal>compile-cpp</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Used these 2 dependencies it is compiling and creating objects from Protoc

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Included everything from resources folder

```
 <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```